# Laravel where also returns empty results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4 to get **all the persons that have a score for a certain event**

This is the query i'm using

```
$event = Person::with(array('eventscore' => function($q){
    $q->where('id', 3);
}))->get();
```

### The problem is that it's also returning the persons that don't have a score in the eventscore table.

This is the output

[image]

Is there any way that i can return only the persons that have a score? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with()` will not limit the `Person`s returned, it will only limit `eventscores`.  If you want only `Person`s that have an event score, you use `has` or `whereHas`.

```
$event = Person::whereHas('eventscore', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', 3);
})->get();
```